# While using s3 static website hosting on aws using cloudfront, getting error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

Hosting one application using s3 static website through cloudfront in one aws account. its working fine but i am migrating to another AWS account its getting error.All files are placed in S3 (Migration Account)
once hitting the url getting the XML code in the screen.
can anyone help me on this

Comment: You need to provide the error for us to help. But most likely, your bucket policies aren't correct

Comment: Eroor "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below." when i am hitting the route 53 domain.

Comment: We need the document tree information. Does it say 404, 401, 403 error?